# count words in a single line without 1 or more spaces from text

Tags: c

here is my algorithm to count words without multiple spaces from gets:

```
int main(){
    char str[300];
    int i=0,words=0;

    gets(str);

    for(i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if(str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\t'){
            words++;
        while(str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\t')
            i++;
        }
    }

    printf("number of words = %d",words);
}
```

I want to transform it in that way it will work with first line of text from file, so i tried this:

```
FILE *fr;
int i=0,words=0;
fr=fopen("myfile.txt","r")
for(i=0; (i=getc(fr) != '\n'); i++){
    if(i != ' ' && i != '\t'){
        words++;
    while(i != ' ' && i != '\t')
        i++;
    }
}
printf("number of words = %d",words)
```

but it doesn´t work, it counts all the characters also with spaces. I the first line in myfile.txt was "Have a      nice         day", I want the result to be equal to 4. Thanks for your advices.

Comment: For your edification: `gets` is such a badly designed SECURITY_HOLE, even the C standard (since C99) got rid of it. It just cannot be used safely.

Comment: you are comparing `i` instead of the read character

Comment: You are using `i` as some sort of "loop counter" and thus incrementing it by 1 (`i++`). But it *is* not a loop counter, it's a character.

Comment: and how it have to looks to comparing the read char? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your code has undefined behavior when at least one word is entered: the nested loop

```
while(str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\t')
    i++;
}
```

disregards the null terminator, and continues reading until it finds a space or a tab. This has a potential of going through the end of the buffer, causing undefined behavior.

To fix this, add a check `str[i] != '\0'`:

```
while(str[i] != '\0' && str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\t')
    i++;
}
```

Your second code snippet is entirely wrong: rather than reading your file line-by-line into a buffer and running your algorithm, you read it character-by-character, and then increment the character code that you get. This will not produce the expected result. Change your code to read the file line-by-line, and fix the nested loop to address the buffer overrun problem as described above.

Note: replace `gets(str)` with `fgets(str, sizeof(str))` to avoid buffer overruns.

Answer (score 0):

In your second algorithm, in the while() loop, you increment i when in fact it is a character from your stream, and without getting further characters from the stream.  So you're not actually moving forward in the string at all.